# Set wildignore in Emacs Evil

Tags: emacs

In Vim, I can set to ignore some extensions when suggesting filenames for autocompletion (`:e` + TAB). I simply put `set wildignore=*.o,*.obj,*.png,*.gif,*.jpg` in my **.vimrc**. How can I achieve the same in Emacs Evil?

Answer (score 0):

The variable `completion-ignored-extensions` works for standard emacs completion. It may work for Evil too.